# mysql - single field array or multiple rows

Tags: mysql, performance

To preface this question I should say I know very little about database efficiency which will become glaringly apparent very shortly.

This is a fairly simple question:

I'd like to store attendance to events within a mysql database.
I've thought of two possible methods (there are more, I'm sure):

1. Create an additional `attendance` row in the `events` table, containing a comma separated list of user ids
2. Create an `attendance` table, containing two columns, `event_id` and `user_id`

My instinct says that method 2 would be the most efficient -- although multiple rows would have to be returned and traversed, this is likely less costly than searching for a particular `user_id` within a concatinated string...

Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: P.S. any other options are also welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option is better. Searching in a comma separated string is time consuming.

However in the 2nd option, make sure the `event_id` and the `user_id` are `FOREIGN KEYS`.

This will `INDEX` the columns and you will have better searching results.

Answer (score 3):

create a new table!

Otherwise you are not taking advantage of the relational aspect of MySQL and every query you run will have to parse the results of the csv entries (horrbily inefficient)